# Rails API JWT Token Authentication working in Dev but not in Prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

I have build a JWT Token based authentication for my Rails API based on this [tutorial](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api).
With the rails server running in Dev Mode, everything works flawless. When I run the rails server in production mode, I get the following errors:

```
Started GET "/profiles" for 10.71.232.74 at 2021-10-19 15:17:37 +0200
Processing by ProfilesController#index as */*
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_request rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 150)
```

Iam now wondering where the difference is between the Dev and Prod mode of the server. Iam using the same database for both, so there is no difference in my environment except the mode of the server.

Comment: Have you whitelisted the prod ip address?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to the JWT token generation. Rails couldnt access the secret_key_base (copy/paste error). In Dev Mode, the server just did some magic in the background to generate the tokens, so it did work. In Production it did not.
After making the secret_key_base available to Rails, it worked.
Overall the error message in rails mislead me.